# Python - how to comma separate everything in a file?

Tags: python

I'm using python 2.7 and I have a file which is organized already.  The file has spaces, numeric values, and integers.  I need everything in this file to be comma-separated.  I've seen questions here which have addressed how to delimit based om some character (like a tab or a space), but nothing on how to delimit every character in a file (Including spaces).

The data is thousands of lines that look like this:

```
DADA?BAC?AB?DABAADB?ADBACABCBA?BBABAB??C    00010001001010111110100011100120110102B0
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Do you want to separate **all** characters (including spaces and other commas) with commas?

Comment: Yep.  Everything in the file.  There are no commas currently in the file.

Comment: Describe the structure of your dataset in a more reproducible way or provide a small piece of it.

Comment: I provided a sample above

Comment: So your desired output is `D,A,D,A,?,B,A,C,?,A,B,?,D,A,B,A,A,D,B,?,A,D,B,A,C,A,B,C,B,A,?,B,B,A,B,A,B,?,?,C, , , , ,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,1,1,0,1,0,2,B,0`? (Or maybe the same with a comma at the end, because newlines are characters too?)

Comment: Your example is correct.  No comma at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Replace every character `x` in a file with `x,`:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
        for line in f:
            o.write(','.join(line))  # No trailing comma
```

Use the following to include a trailing comma:

```
o.write(''.join(x + ',' for x in line)) # Trailing comma
```

Comment: One of these two is definitely what he asked for (depending on whether he realizes that newlines are characters). I doubt it's what he _wants_, but I have no idea _what_ he wants, and this is what he asked for, so… about as good as it can get.

Comment: @abarnert I'm with you, I can't imagine what value comma delimiting every single char in a file would have but hey, each to their own I guess

Comment: You don't need to waste memory creating a temporary list in your second example `''.join(x + ',' for x in line)` :)

Comment: I'm running this code and it is deleting everything in the source text file.  Nothing is being written to the destination file.

Comment: @user3476845 You did change `input.txt` to the correct input file right?  This code wouldn't modify the input file in any way.

Comment: @Jkdc Your "no trailing comma" solution has trailing commas, and your "trailing comm" solution additionally adds commas at the start of lines.

Comment: @Jkdc  Yes.  I named all the files correctly.  Triple checked.  The filenames work with other scripts, as well.

Answer (score 1):

This will put commas between every single character in `data`:

```
data = ','.join(data)
```

Comment: This is Python at its best. Recall "There should be one - and preferably only one - obvious way to do it."